# In Moodle Storage File System Selection Storage File System is only showing Default "Please, select " Option , Cant specify azure blob storage

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, moodle

[image: Admin tools/ Object storage file system/ Plugin Settings screen]

I was trying to Configure the storage of Moodle LMS in my local windows pc . I want to store the files uploaded through the Moodle should be save in the Azure Blob storage that I have created .
I have seen a post that **moodle-tool_objectfs** plugin can do this .

[https://moodle.org/plugins/tool_objectfs](https://stackoverflow.com)

I refer this documentation .
I have installed the plugin but I cant specify My azure Blob storage path in the *Storage File System* in the **Storage File System Selection** . It is only showing the default option "Please, select" .
How can I Add Specify it to my Azure Blob Storage ...?
Is there any other methods that I should try ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe double check the installation instructions on github

https://github.com/catalyst/moodle-tool_objectfs?tab=readme-ov-file#installation

Looks like they are slightly different to the Moodle website

There is a local plugin for Azure Blob Storage that needs to be installed

> Clone moodle-local_azure_storage into local/azure_storage for Azure Blob Storage,

Comment: thanks, it worked.  I have done the installation steps  and established the connection to azure  blob storage.


 connection and permision check files are generated  generated in my azure blob container after the installation .

 But my files are not adding to azure while i  upload them in moodle.